# Is the given function a solution of given matrix ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> I'm trying to solve a matrix ODE $X'(t)=AX(t)$ where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-3& 0\\0&-1&0\\-1&5&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Suppose $X(t)=(a(t),b(t),c(t))$ then since $b'(t)=-b(t)$ so $b(t)=e^{-t}$. Is this correct that

> $a(t)= 2e^{2t}- e^{-t},b(t)=e^{-t}$ and $c(t)=2e^{2t}+e^{-t}$ ?

I tried to put the values in the system but these values do not satisfy the system. Am i doing some mistake?

Comment: Some of the coefficients are arbitrary constants, for example $b(t)=b_0 e^{-t}$ with a real number $b_0$

Comment: Maybe it‘s better to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: The 2nd row and the third column show that -1 and 1 are eigenvalues. The trace of the matrix is 2, hence the third eigenvalue is 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just in general take the enties in the matrix and derive a solution just from them. In your case you're lucky that you can easily find the value of $b$. So as you've noticed you have $b' = -b$, so $b= c_1e^{-t}$ (Don't forget the constant multiples).

Plugging in the first equation you get $a' = 2a - 3c_1e^{-t}$, which is a linear ODE and can be easily solved to get that $a = c_1e^{-t} + c_2e^{2t}$

Finally you can substitute in the last equation $c' = -a + 5b + c$, i.e. $c' = c + 4c_1e^{-t} - c_2e^{2t}$, which can be solved to get $c= -2c_1e^{-t} - c_2e^{2t} + c_3e^t$

But in general finidng a starting point as we did with $b$ is hard. So then we have to use the fact that the solutions of the system are given by $e^{A} = I + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} + \cdots$.

Unfortunately it's hard to find the powers of $A$, so therefore we must diagonalize. Doing this we get that $A=PDP^{-1}$ ,where:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0& 1\\-1&0&0\\2&1&1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \quad D=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0& 0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2 \end{bmatrix}$$

So now:

$$X = e^{A}C = e^{PDP^{-1}}C = Pe^{D}P^{-1}C = P\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t}&0& 0\\0&e^t&0\\0&0&e^{2t} \end{bmatrix}P^{-1}C = \begin{bmatrix}-c_1e^{-t} + c_3e^{2t}\\-c_1e^{-t}\\2c_1e^{-t} + c_2e^t + c_3e^{2t} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! So the given $(a(t),b(t),c(t))$ is not a solution because for instance the coefficient of $e^{-t}$ has same sign in $a,b$ as you showed while in the given solution they have opposite sign?

Comment: @Dontknowanything If you're refering to my first solution in which I didn't use matrix then you're wrong. Both of them give the same set of solution. Note that if you substitute $-c_1$ and $-c_2$ in the place of $c_1$ and $c_2$ you will get the same form. But as I said using the not-matrix method is sometimes imposible. In your problem we were lucky a bit

Comment: No, i was referring to $a(t)= 2e^{2t}- e^{-t},b(t)=e^{-t}$ and $c(t)=2e^{2t}+e^{-t}$ the solution given in my question. I was saying that these values of $a(t),b(t) \text {and} c(t)$ does not form a solution right?

Comment: No they don't. You can check whether the satisfy the system. In fact all solutions are of the form I have written, so if they don't satisfy it then they aren't solutions